# Nvidia Optimus dual screen setup on TP W520

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus

Hi I'm trying to setup Nvidia Optimus with Driver 331 from xorg-edgers with an external Monitor on Displayport.

TP Display resolution: 1920x1080

Ext. Display resolution: 1920x1200

Mirroring mode works now : [image: mirrored]

but when I try to use the extended desktop the desktop and all applications are only stretched to the whole size and mouse interaction is a pain because it does not fit to the
viewed desktop:
[image: stretched desktop]

How can I change this behavior?

Thx

Update:
With latest release of xorg-edgers it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

Press 'Start+P'.

You can toggle between multiple monitor modes.

Comment: Non of the available modes I can switch to has a better result

Comment: resolution is added to question